# Whas this Error Code and how can i get rid of it?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

Im using this code to query the balance of the logged-in address

```
// get sellPrice
function sellPrice() {
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
        contract.sellPrice(address, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err, 'err');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('sell_price').innerHTML = result;
            }
        });
    });
}
sellPrice();
```

But when i call it I get this error in the console:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: invalid argument 1: hex number > 64 bits {code: -32602, message: "invalid argument 1: hex number > 64 bits"}
```

I cant really find anything on google or with metamask that explains how i can get rid of this error

Comment: Your code is a mess, and it is missing information critical to answering your question. For example, why are you not using `accounts` anywhere? What is `address`? Why should we care about `innerHTML` for the sake of answering your problems?

Comment: In addition to that, you need to do some basic debugging before posting your problems here. For example, print `error` and `accounts` before you call `contract.sellPrice`.

Comment: Also, please bother to explain the meaning of "I get this error" - is it printed when you do `console.log(err, 'err')`? Is it an exception thrown somewhere? If yes, at which line in your code does this exception take place?

Comment: console.log(err, 'err')
VM14201:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: err is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: innerHTML is used to print out the value of the result variable, but there is an error because of the HEX beeing to long

Comment: On line 77 is get this error
{code: -32602, message: "invalid argument 1: hex number > 64 bits"}
code: -32602
message: "invalid argument 1: hex number > 64 bits"
__proto__: Object

Comment: and on line 1 i get this error
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: invalid argument 1: hex number > 64 bits

Comment: and when i googled for this error, nothing comes up that is related to my issue, they talking about this beeing a geth error, but i dont use geth and they are talking about blocks, but im not using Blocks i just want to call this getter function.

Comment: address is the contract address, accounts is supposed to be the currently logged in account but i cant acces it anywhere and it shows up as undefined

Comment: You're not answering any of my questions. "is it printed **when** you do `console.log(err, 'err')`?" - this is a question, not a request for you to run `console.log(err, 'err')`. "On line 77" - how exactly are we supposed to guess what is line 77 in your code??? Same for "line 1". Please extend **your post** so that all these questions are answered, including whatever is required for us to know things like the value of `address` and so on.

Comment: here is my code https://pastebin.com/FEsgFiVh
Yes the above error is in the console.log

Comment: Please post ONLY the part or parts of your code which are relevant to the actual problem at hand, after doing a minimal research to detect those relevant parts. Otherwise, you are just asking others to do this work for you. And please post those parts in the question (not in the comment-section), and in plain text (no images or links).